# online notification in android

Tags: android, notifications

I've built an Android application by android studio.
I want to be associated with users online and notify changes and news.**even when my application is closed.**

This is what is on my mind,I have web server, i want create a internet connection listener and when connection is available,application or a part of it connect with the server and get new information and notify the user with a notification.**even when my application is closed.**

How can I implement and enforce it?

Answer (score 1):

Try "Google Cloud Messaging."

Per their [Developer Console Help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en): "Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) is a free service that helps developers send messages across multiple platforms: Android, iOS, and Chrome. For example, a server can send messages directly to single devices, groups of devices, or devices subscribed to topics. Also, the application on a device can send messages directly to a server and to devices belonging to the same group."

Use the Google Cloud Messaging service alongside the Google Plugin for Eclipse. [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/ios-push-notifications/) explains as: "When targeting Android devices, it is easy to get started by using Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE). GPE allows you to generate an App Engine Connected Android Project that provides the basic logic needed for sending push notifications using Google Cloud Messaging for Android from a mobile backend running on Google App Engine."

This could send messages for you without having to do the work on your own server.

Answer (score 0):

No,These systems are always some limitations and managed with others.I do not need to communicate with iOS or chrome ,I need to design a system that's all for me.Experience has shown me great services, such as Google services and any other company affected by political issues.for example i live in iran right now.
All production-oriented and knowledge-based services for this country is banned.
**due to this problems i prefer to have my own messaging and notification system.**